# Extract data points in contour map

Tags: matlab

My data is xy rings with z as a height.  I create a contour map of the data.  I need to be able to create xy data points with the z component having a value somewhere between the 2 contour lines.  Then extract all of the xyz data.  I have found a few programs to extract the data but it is only x,y data and it is basically the xy data that I originally started with.

Comment: How are you currently plotting the contour? You should be able to extract what you need from the contour matrix which is an optional output of `contour`.

Comment: What do you mean by "rings"? What do you mean by "extract all of the xyz data"?